# When trying to print an array from sub only the first element prints

Tags: perl, subroutine

I'm writing a Perl script that requires me to pull out a whole column from a file and manipulate it. For example take out column A and compare it to another column in another file

```
A B C

A B C

A B C
```

So far I have:

```
sub routine1
{
    ( $_ = <FILE> )

    {
        next if $. < 2; # to skip header of file

        my @array1 = split(/\t/, $_);
        my $file1 = $array1[@_];

        return $file1;
    }
}
```

I have most of it done. The only problem is that when I call to print the subroutine it only prints the first element in the array (i.e. it will only print one A).

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile. Are you sure you don't have something more like `while ($_ = <FILE>) { ... }` ?

Comment: That's odd. It compiles for me. No, I don't have something like that. The code above is exactly how I have it.

Comment: What version of Perl do you have?

Comment: I'm currently on perl v.5.16.3. When i type in "print routine1(1)" only one A prints out instead of the whole column

Comment: I'm guessing you have a semi-colon after `( $_ = <FILE> )`, since even in Perl 5.16.3 I get `syntax error at foo line 10, near ")

{"`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: I think the OP must have a `while` before those parentheses, otherwise the `next` will just exit the bare block immediately and the subroutine will return `undef` or the empty list.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that what you actually have is this

```
sub routine1
{
    while ( $_ = <FILE> )

    {
        next if $. < 2; # to skip header of file

        my @array1 = split(/\t/, $_);
        my $file1 = $array1[@_];

        return $file1;
    }
}
```

which *does* compile, and reads the file one line at a time in a loop.

There are two problems here. First of all, as soon as your loop has read the first line of the file (after the header) the `return` statement exits the subroutine, returning the only field it has read. That is why you get only a single value.

Secondly, you have indexed your `@array1` with `@_`. What that does is take the *number of elements* in `@_` (usually one) and use that to index `@array1`. You will therefore always get the second element of the array.

I'm not clear what you expect as a result, but you should write something like this. It accumulates all the values from the specified column into the array `@retval`, and passes the file handle into the subroutine instead of just using a global, which is poor programming practice.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'myfile.txt' or die $!;
my @column2 = routine1($fh, 1);
print "@column2\n";

sub routine1 {

  my ($fh, $index) = @_;
  my @retval;

  while ($_ = <$fh>) {
    next if $. < 2;    # to skip header of file
    my @fields = split /\t/;
    my $field  = $fields[$index];
    push @retval, $field;
  }

  return @retval;
}
```

**output**

```
B B
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing most of your sub with something like this:

```
 my @aColumn = ();
 while (<FILE>) 
 {
    chomp;
    ($Acol, $Bcol, $Ccol) = split("\t");
    push(@aColumn, $Acol);
  }
  return @aColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

Jumping to the end, the following will pull out the first column in your file `blah.txt` and put it in an array for you to manipulate later:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = 'blah.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $file;

my @firstcol;

while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my @cols = split;
    push @firstcol, $cols[0];
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \@firstcol;
```

What you have right now isn't actually looping on the contents of the file, so you aren't going to be building an array.

Comment: No need to `chomp` when using `split` w/o explicit parameters, as it'll remove the trailing newlines.

Comment: TY @Kenosis, I didn't know that.  I'd still probably choose to write an explicit [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) in anything but a perl one-liner as I can see introducing a bug later on very easily.  And I'd definitely use it when trying to teach a new person how to code, like in this example.  Nevertheless, appreciate the tip.

Comment: You're most welcome.  You make a very good point about using `chomp` explicitly when working with a person new to Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Here's are a few items for you to consider when crafting a subroutine solution for obtaining an array of column values from a file:

- Skip the file header before entering the `while` loop to avoid a line-number comparison for each file line.
- `split` only the number of columns you need by using `split`'s LIMIT.  This can significantly speed up the process.
- Optionally, initialize a `local` copy of Perl's `@ARGV` with the file name, and let Perl handle the file i/o.

[Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin)'s solution to create a subroutine that takes both the file name column number is excellent, so it's implemented below, too:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @colVals = getFileCol( 'File.txt', 0 );
print "@colVals\n";

sub getFileCol {
    local @ARGV = (shift);
    my ( $col, @arr ) = shift;

    <>;    # skip file header
    while (<>) {
        my $val = ( split ' ', $_, $col + 2 )[$col] or next;
        push @arr, $val;
    }

    return @arr;
}
```

Output on your dataset:

```
A A
```

Hope this helps!